# ofstream writing everything to my file twice

Tags: c++, ofstream

So I have a short program to generate a cost matrix to a file but when I run it everything is showing up in the file twice.

Here's what I have:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

      int V = rand() % 15 + 5;
      int graph[V][V];
      for( int i = 0; i < V; i++ ){
       for( int j = 0; j < V; j++ ){
         graph[i][j] = rand() % 50;
       }
      }
     for( int i = 0; i < V; i++ ){
        graph[i][i] = 0;
     }

   ofstream fout;
   fout.open( "graphTest.txt", ios::app );

   fout << V << endl;

   for( int i = 0; i < V; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < V; j++ ){
      fout << graph[i][j] << ", ";
    }
    fout << endl;
  }

 fout.close();
return 0;
}
```

And here's what the file shows:

```
18
0, 27, 15, 43, 35, 36, 42, 49, 21, 12, 27, 40, 9, 13, 26, 40, 26, 22, 
36, 0, 18, 17, 29, 32, 30, 12, 23, 17, 35, 29, 2, 22, 8, 19, 17, 43, 
6, 11, 0, 29, 23, 21, 19, 34, 37, 48, 24, 15, 20, 13, 26, 41, 30, 6, 
23, 12, 20, 0, 31, 5, 25, 34, 27, 36, 5, 46, 29, 13, 7, 24, 45, 32, 
45, 14, 17, 34, 0, 43, 0, 37, 8, 26, 28, 38, 34, 3, 1, 4, 49, 32, 
10, 26, 18, 39, 12, 0, 36, 44, 39, 45, 20, 34, 28, 17, 1, 47, 2, 17, 
42, 2, 6, 1, 30, 36, 0, 15, 39, 44, 19, 40, 29, 31, 17, 47, 21, 31, 
25, 9, 27, 17, 6, 47, 3, 0, 15, 6, 33, 19, 24, 28, 21, 32, 29, 3, 
19, 20, 18, 8, 15, 40, 49, 46, 0, 18, 45, 46, 1, 21, 5, 29, 38, 14, 
28, 41, 0, 43, 0, 34, 14, 24, 14, 0, 6, 43, 41, 27, 15, 9, 36, 32, 
1, 37, 28, 25, 7, 24, 21, 8, 45, 29, 0, 35, 43, 18, 28, 43, 11, 28, 
29, 26, 4, 43, 13, 13, 38, 6, 40, 4, 18, 0, 38, 19, 17, 17, 46, 24, 
43, 20, 33, 40, 49, 22, 25, 44, 40, 5, 39, 4, 0, 19, 32, 42, 14, 47, 
7, 5, 4, 48, 11, 22, 28, 49, 43, 46, 18, 40, 22, 0, 10, 5, 1, 11, 
30, 28, 5, 20, 36, 44, 26, 22, 15, 8, 16, 32, 8, 24, 0, 12, 24, 0, 
36, 2, 49, 29, 0, 18, 21, 23, 31, 31, 30, 33, 44, 10, 13, 0, 31, 49, 
46, 9, 23, 13, 18, 40, 45, 26, 16, 34, 40, 40, 34, 26, 42, 36, 0, 45, 
6, 29, 18, 37, 12, 48, 22, 9, 9, 36, 10, 42, 37, 6, 1, 13, 22, 0, 
18
0, 27, 15, 43, 35, 36, 42, 49, 21, 12, 27, 40, 9, 13, 26, 40, 26, 22, 
36, 0, 18, 17, 29, 32, 30, 12, 23, 17, 35, 29, 2, 22, 8, 19, 17, 43, 
6, 11, 0, 29, 23, 21, 19, 34, 37, 48, 24, 15, 20, 13, 26, 41, 30, 6, 
23, 12, 20, 0, 31, 5, 25, 34, 27, 36, 5, 46, 29, 13, 7, 24, 45, 32, 
45, 14, 17, 34, 0, 43, 0, 37, 8, 26, 28, 38, 34, 3, 1, 4, 49, 32, 
10, 26, 18, 39, 12, 0, 36, 44, 39, 45, 20, 34, 28, 17, 1, 47, 2, 17, 
42, 2, 6, 1, 30, 36, 0, 15, 39, 44, 19, 40, 29, 31, 17, 47, 21, 31, 
25, 9, 27, 17, 6, 47, 3, 0, 15, 6, 33, 19, 24, 28, 21, 32, 29, 3, 
19, 20, 18, 8, 15, 40, 49, 46, 0, 18, 45, 46, 1, 21, 5, 29, 38, 14, 
28, 41, 0, 43, 0, 34, 14, 24, 14, 0, 6, 43, 41, 27, 15, 9, 36, 32, 
1, 37, 28, 25, 7, 24, 21, 8, 45, 29, 0, 35, 43, 18, 28, 43, 11, 28, 
29, 26, 4, 43, 13, 13, 38, 6, 40, 4, 18, 0, 38, 19, 17, 17, 46, 24, 
43, 20, 33, 40, 49, 22, 25, 44, 40, 5, 39, 4, 0, 19, 32, 42, 14, 47, 
7, 5, 4, 48, 11, 22, 28, 49, 43, 46, 18, 40, 22, 0, 10, 5, 1, 11, 
30, 28, 5, 20, 36, 44, 26, 22, 15, 8, 16, 32, 8, 24, 0, 12, 24, 0, 
36, 2, 49, 29, 0, 18, 21, 23, 31, 31, 30, 33, 44, 10, 13, 0, 31, 49, 
46, 9, 23, 13, 18, 40, 45, 26, 16, 34, 40, 40, 34, 26, 42, 36, 0, 45, 
6, 29, 18, 37, 12, 48, 22, 9, 9, 36, 10, 42, 37, 6, 1, 13, 22, 0,
```

I'm not sure why it's looping through twice

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run the program twice?  `fout.open( "graphTest.txt", ios::app );` means it will not overwrite what is already in the file but instead add new data starting at the end of the file.

Comment: As said by @NathanOliver, `ios::app` corresponds to "appending" to the file. Edit: I'm positive that  this is the case as `fout << V << endl;` is not called in a loop whatsoever and it appears twice in your output. Hope this clears things up for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You opened your file with `ios::app` flags, such it appends the data to an existing file from a former run:

```
fout.open( "graphTest.txt", ios::app );
                         // ^^^^^^^^
```

Open your file using the `ios::trunc` flag to overwrite the data from previous runs:

```
fout.open( "graphTest.txt", ios::trunc );
                         // ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

As a side note:

The reason why you are seeing the same sequence in the file as the product of subsequent runs your program is because you missed to initialize the random generator. You have to call e.g.

```
seed(time(NULL));
```

once in the beginning of `main()`.